# Simple way to use looping in java

Tags: java, for-loop

This is example for my looping code:

```
int outsideLoop = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    outsideLoop += i;
    System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
}
System.out.println("Outside loop is: " + outsideLoop);
```

My friend is said that using `int i = 1; i < 11; i++` is a primitive ways.
is there any quick way to looping than to use this code?

Comment: What do you mean by "primitive"? There is nothing wrong with using `int` but your variable `outsideLoop` is confusing me, you should rename it to something like `loopCount`.

Comment: I am not sure what the deal is. Maybe you should ask your "friend" what is so bad about "primitive" ...

Comment: Don't talk to this friend ever again.

Comment: as far as i am concerned, I feel that the way you are doing it is the fastest and the best way

Comment: That is how a for loop works. Maybe you friend is referring to for-each loop syntax, like `String someArray[] = ... ; for (String str : someArray)` which doesnt need a loop counter any more. But when you want a **for** loop to count something, then you have to use a for loop that counts something. Other languages might have more elegant ways to write that down, but not Java.

Comment: If your "friend" was aiming towards Bathsheba's closed-form solution, then you should demand that he stops talking in riddles. "Your solution is crap" is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @GhostCat did you have a example to use `for (String str : someArray)`?

Comment: The example is already there. someArray is well, some array, that you somehow need to initialize. And hint: there are *search* engines out there. You go there, and you type words like "java for each loop"; and guess what, there will be tons and tons and tons of links with examples.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks, it's helping. I think this is an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work

Answer (score 3):

A good friend would tell you that there is a *closed-form* solution for `outsideLoop`. In other words, there's no need to use a `for` loop at all, which saves computation time.

`outsideLoop = n * (n + 1) / 2`, where, in your case, `n` is 10.

This comes from the sum of an *arithmetic progression*.